étale fundamental group of a connected algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic p
I am looking for an explanation of the fact that the étale fundamental group of a connected unipotent algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, where  $char(k)=p$ has no non-trivial quotients of order prime to $p$.
I understand that quotients of the fundamental group correspond to étale covers, and that G is an affine scheme.

This is false (e.g., the nth power map on $\mathbb{G}_m$ for $\text{gcd}(p,n)=1$). Are you sure you asked the correct question?

You are right... i think we also require the hypothesis of unipotent...

I think this boils down to the vanishing of the first cohomology of affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ with coefficients in $\mu_{\ell}$, and the fact that a connected unipotent algebraic group is schematically isomorphic to affine $n$ space.
